# Anyone know of a good PHP ORM that DOES NOT use PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, orm, pdo

I'm building a webapp for a department on a large college campus that will eventually be run on the enterprise servers ( I use the term 'enterprise' loosely ).

**The problem is that the admins have refused to compile and enable any PDO extension other than SQLite.  They do have mysql and mysqli enabled though, so it's not a total loss.**

So does anybody out here know of a good ORM for PHP that does NOT rely on PDO as it's main engine?

I've already looked at Doctrine and Propel (both excellent frameworks), though could not figure out how to rip PDO out from inside them.

**Edit**:  Here is the response I've gotten from the admins on the server:

> Sean,
>
> We have tried, unsuccessfully, several times to build PHP with the PDO extension included.  The reason we haven't been successful is complicated, but basically stems from the fact that the web envoronment was originally set up with some database driver libraries compiled staticly and others compiled dynamically, the mix causing PDO to complain loudly.  The reason things were were done this way was due to a bug in early versions of PHP 5.x that is no longer an issue today (or at least less of one), but switching is difficult because the change would require modifications to php.ini files and, since every site (including sites on [*server redacted*]) has its own php.ini (roughly 22,000 files total, many of which are modified by users)  it is very difficult to push out that change (and not making the change causes errors [I don't recall if they are fatal or not] on pages served from accounts with non-updated files).

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use PDO? It is the how you(future of) should connect to your database!

Comment: Well if you use Propel 1.0 (i think PDO came along in 1.2) it uses Creole as the abstraction instead of PDO (i think creole uses mysqli for mysql connectivity under the hood). In terms of Doctrine you would need to implement your own custom drivers - which im pretty sure would be no small feat given its complexity.

Comment: There exists a PDO emulation for PHP4, which also provides an alternative binding on PHP5. Link bottom right on http://www.xpdo.org/  - Though it would still require some rewriting to use it. And obviously that's also a substandard option.

Comment: That sounds like an odd decision to make! The only alternative that comes to my mind is [ADODb Active Record](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm) - I can't speak to its worthiness though

Comment: Why would you ever NOT want PDO?

Comment: I LOVE PDO!  The server this will be deployed on does not support PDO and the admins have refused to enable it.  I'm stuck.

Comment: @Sean Madden: Just stand your ground and insist on using PDO. What is their reason for refusing to install PDO? Perhaps you can help them work through whatever issue that is.

Comment: Why not just use mysqli or mysql? Write your own queries, it isn't that hard.

Comment: @Sean - switch to a different host. Given that email, they have a hacky solution and you can't possibly be getting good bandwidth and execution speeds if they have 22,000 .ini files

Comment: @seth.vargo => It's for a college department on campus, that is the environment for the web environment that the IT department manages.

Comment: @Sean - I fail to see your point. Someone isn't doing their job correctly. Instead of you hacking a solution to a hacked solution just to get something that works, actually make someone do their job and fix it

Comment: @Sean You should drop your provider like a hot potato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that every modern ORM relies on PDO as it's a standard database driver.

If you have [MySQLi extension](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) enabled then you should be able to write your own PDO (IIRC MySQLi supports everything that PDO does).

```
if (extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') == false) {
    class PDO {
        protected $connection;

        public function __construct($dsn, $username = null, $password = null, array $driver_options = array()) {
            $this->connection = new MySQLi(...);
        }
    }

    class PDOStatement { ... }
    class PDOException extends RuntimeException { ... }
}
```

You'll have to implement whole PDO API but at least it will works.

Comment: Now I'm not sure how similar mysqli and PDO interfaces are. But if some functions are named the same and take the same arguments you could use the above approach together with the __call magic method to pass on calls to the mysqli object indtance. Then you would not have to implement the entire PDO interface but just the functions that differs in name and/or arguments.

Comment: I think this is ultimately what I'll go with.  Thanks for all the help guys.