# PHP ORM for MySQL without PDO

Tags: php, mysql, orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know of a good PHP ORM that DOES NOT use PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708117/anyone-know-of-a-good-php-orm-that-does-not-use-pdo)

I have been using RedBeanPHP for my ORM for a number of projects, but the webhost I'm currently working with does not support PDO. Since PDO is required for RedBeanPHP, I cannot use it.

Is there a PHP ORM for MySQL that does not make use of PDO?

Comment: move hosts is the obvious solution

Comment: Punish the web host for such a malfeasance.  But really, PDO is enabled by default since PHP 5.1.0.  All they need to do is say they want a specific PDO driver.  I don't know of any ORM that doesn't use PDO.  You can look at [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) which has some non-PDO drivers supported by their OO interface, but its not full ORM out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree the real answer is you need to move hosting providers.  If they don't offer a php build with pdo enabled, I can only image what other  issues they have.

The answer you're looking for however will vary based on what type of DB libraries you are allowed...  mysql, mysqli, mdb2, adodb, etc...

Most likely, you'll need to find an older version of an ORM, back in the day when they allowed you to specify if you wanted to use mysqli or pdo.

However, until we know what you have, no one can answer your question fully.

Run `php -m` on the command line and paste the result into the question so we can see what options you have.

Comment: It's OK, I'll probably end up switching hosts. Thanks.

Comment: @jburns20 if this is the route you found correct, please mark the answer correct (and maybe upvote my response....)

Comment: db.php orm allows you to implement your own connection link class to use whatever mysql connector you wish http://dbphp.net/connect-using-custom-link/